# Dual boot UEFI, last grub entry gets set in bios

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Running the following:

Asus x99-ws, NVME ssd with Ubuntu 18, SATA SSD with Windows 10. 
NVME UEFI is set default in "bios".

Issue is this:

After I boot windows from the grub menu, the next reboot boots automatically on windows. It does this by changing the boot order in bios. Grub never shows.

Fixable by going to the UEFI bios settings, and changing boot order.

How do i stop grub2 from setting a different bios boot order? I need it to be there by default.

( one way is to add Ubuntu UEFI to the windows bcd / NOT the way i want to do this )

Comment: It is either your UEFI or Windows. Grub only will change boot order to make grub first on reinstall or major update. Windows on major update will change it to be first, but that should not be on every reboot. Have you updated UEFI form Asus? Does it have a way to change settings and lock them (most do not).

Comment: As I understood from your explanation this is done by UEFI bios, check it settings, may be there option to remember boot device and to turn it off/lock.

Comment: Bios ( Asus UEFi settings ), is the lastest version. No way of "locking" settings. 
Windows has updates locked down, has not done any updates in the last 2 months. 
The issue is with grub. I had Ubuntu on a different sata ssd. This did not happen. 
Reinstalled Ubuntu on a new NVME, and this happends. 
grub somehow changes the "bios" boot order.